# Assigning a subscribed value to a variable : Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that's displaying a value in

{{getData}}

if I fire the onDo() with a button click. onDo() is initiating a GET request to a server.

The server is giving back the response, and I am subscribing it. I am assigning the subscribed value to this.getData and being able to show it successfully in my component template with {{getData}}.
I can also get a print of the data in the console inside .subscribe().
But I tried to print it outside the .subscribe() and it's not displaying anything.

What I actually want to do is: assign the value of getData to MyVar.
Here is my code:

```
@Component({


template: `

...

<p>{{getData}}</p>

...

`,

providers: [MyService]

})

export class MyComponent{

    getData: string;
    MyVar: string;

    constructor(private _myService: MyService, private _router: Router){}

    onDo(){

        this._myService.getSomething()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
                error => this._router.navigate(['error']),
                () => console.log('Get data inside subscribe: '+ this.getData)
                );

            console.log('Get data outside subscribe'+this.getData);
            this.MyVar = this.getData;

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
```

is a function that is passed to `subscribe(...)` to be called when the data arrives from the server.

You `console.log(...)` is called immediately after above function is passed to `subscribe`, but that doesn't mean the data is already there.

Just move the code inside `subscribe(...)` and it will work as expected.

Comment: The subscribe is supporting only three parameters. Here are fat arrows with data =>, error=>, ()=> and I'm using each of them for something else. Now where, and how should I put the expression: "this.MyVar = this.getData;" ?

Comment: Add `{}` like `data => {this.getData = JSON.stringify(data); otherStatementsHere; }`, then you can add as much code as you want.